# My script can't access file at temporary location

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, file-get-contents, snapchat

I have a html for that asks for *username*, *password* and *image file*.

Then I use this script to upload it to snapchat story:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_dir = $target_dir . basename( $_FILES["uploadFile"]["name"]);
$uploadOk=1;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadFile"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["uploadFile"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}

$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$img = $_FILES["uploadFile"]["tmp_name"];

require_once("src/snapchat.php");
$snapchat = new Snapchat($user, $pass);
$id = $snapchat->upload(Snapchat::MEDIA_IMAGE,file_get_contents($img));
$snapchat->setStory($id, Snapchat::MEDIA_IMAGE, 10);
?>
```

But it does not work!
It keeps saying:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(/tmp/phpCO1pki) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u753295385/public_html/run_command.php on line 18
```

There's probably something I'm forgetting. If you could help me that'd be AWESOME!

Answer (score 1):

That's because the file is not there any more - you moved it:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadFile"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir)) {
```

This function moves the file from temporary directory somewhere else. So either do not move, or use the target location - `$target_dir`.

I don't know what Snapchat is, but if you're just using the contents of the file, you don't have to move it at all. Just check for the `$_FILES["uploadFile"]["error"]` and then pass the temporary name:

```
$id = $snapchat->upload(Snapchat::MEDIA_IMAGE,file_get_contents($_FILES["uploadFile"]["tmp_name"]));
```

Comment: Oh, another comment editor... Please post code at external site. Post it before posting the comment. I will not dissapear in few secconds, so there's no hurry.

Comment: I updated my script, now it gives me no error, but doesn´t upload to pic to snapchat either.

(snapchat is an app like instagram etc)

Comment: Well, that's a different problem. I never used it, so I can't help, especially since there's no error. Try to dump the image to the output by `imagepng(imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents(//path//)))`

Comment: I don't know what that means :(

Comment: That means: Your question was solved. Ask another, after you find out some errors ("It's not working" question will be closed here). Or join some IRC channel where somebody may help you with subsequent problems.

Comment: Hey! it's working, it only uploads jpg though, it wont work when I use PNG.
Is there anyway to only allow jpg or automatically change the extension to jpg?

Comment: Changing extension is pointless. JPG and PNG are diferent way of saving the image. Extension is just part of filename. You can give it `.txt` and it's till an image.

Comment: Ok but when I change the extension from png to jpg it works, it seems to work even if it's just a part of the filename and nothing more.

Comment: Well, somebody is cheating during the check.